# uiRouter generates the correct a-href but nothing happens when it is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using the uiRouter in my angularjs application but in a specific situation it is not working how i expected. I want to pass a parameter from one view to another through the URL.
Here is my route configuration:

```
let configurations = {
    url: '/clientes-consulta/:status',
    controller: 'ClientesConsultaCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    templateUrl: 'clientes/consulta/clientes-consulta.html',
    title: 'Clientes Consulta'
};

$stateProvider.state('app.clientes-consulta', configuracoes);
```

and here is my html

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-large"
   ui-sref="app.clientes-consulta({status:$ctrl._enumStatusCLiente.PENDENTE})"
   ng-show="$ctrl._notificacoes.length > 0">
       Go to notifications
</a>
```

When i run this code and inspect the "Go to notifications" link, the router generates a valid link (if i copy it and paste in the browser's address bar my view shows up):

```
href="#!/clientes-consulta/PENDENTE"
```

**OBS:** I have seen a lot of questions on the same subject but none of them worked out for me and I also have other cases in my project working fine. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: **OBS2**: When i paste it directly into the address bar i can get the 'status' parameter with the expected value 'PENDENTE'.

Comment: hey, can you be more specific, what exactly u want to ask?

Comment: i want to know what im missing.. why isn't this working?